# How to evaluate sphere integral $\int_{v} \nabla \cdot (x^5\hat{x}+y^5\hat{y}+z^5\hat{z})\ dxdydz $

Tags: integration, divergence-operator

Consider the following integral:

$\int_{v} \nabla \cdot V \ dxdydz $

where $v$ is a sphere of radius R so that

$x^2+y^2+z^2 = R^2$

and the vector $V$ is given by

$V = x^5\hat{x}+y^5\hat{y}+z^5\hat{z}$

I attempted to introduce a vector $V_2$ so that:

$V_2 = x^3\hat{x}+y^3\hat{y}+z^3\hat{z}$

and

$\nabla \cdot V_2 = 3x^2+3y^2+3z^2=3R^2$

Using vector identities I would arrive at:

$\frac{5}{9}(\nabla \cdot V_2)^2 = \nabla \cdot V$

This produces $\nabla \cdot V=5R^4$

I then take $R$ as the argument, change the system to an spherical system and do the integral. Obtaining:

$\int_{v} \nabla \cdot V \ dv =  \frac{20}{7}\pi R^7$

Yet this is different from the answer one gets from the numerical evaluation of the integral which is just:
$\frac{12}{7}\pi R^7$

So what am I doing wrong?

Edit. The Vector Identity result was wrong. So the new questions would be>
Is there any vector identity that would help us solve this integral?

Comment: It looks funky, since $\nabla \cdot V = 5 (x^4 + y^4 + z^4) \neq 5 (x^2+y^2 + z^2)^2 = 5 R^4$ right?

Comment: So I checked the calculation. The numerical result is correct. I converted everything to polar coordinates and then integrated the (nasty) $\sin$, $\cos$ terms out.

Comment: Yes I found an error using the vector identities. So I am changing my question.

Comment: Just do the problem directly. If you think about symmetry, you can make the integral much simpler by doing, say, just $\int z^4 \,dV$ in the appropriate coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to compute the integral as belows,

$$I=\int_{v} \nabla \cdot V \ dxdydz =5\int_{v}(x^4+y^4+z^4)dxdydz$$

The integral is symmetric with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$, that is,

$$\int_{v}x^4 dxdydz =\int_{v} y^4dxdydz = \int_{v}z^4dxdydz$$

For example, the first equality is obtained by switching $x$ and $y$ in the expression $\int_{v}x^4 dxdydz $.

Thus, simplify the integral and then use the spherical coordinates,

$$I =15\int_{v}z^4dxdydz=15\int_0^R\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}r^6\cos^4\theta\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$$

$$I =15\int_0^R r^6dr\int_0^{\pi}\cos^4\theta\sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi=\frac{12\pi}{7}R^7$$

Comment: Can you expand a little bit on the 15 and $z^4$

Comment: @Cab Zx - no problem. I added a few lines in the answer

Comment: I understand now. Than you.